# Mysqli вывод

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

Подскажите как вывести запись? я новчиок в MySQLi в mysql я хорошо знаю) посмотрел синтаксис одинаковый почти, но все равно не получается вот что я написал.

```
<?php

mysqli_connect ('localhost','new','new','new');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
echo "<h2>Вывод записей:</h2>";

while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo {$user['name']};

}

?>
```

подскажите где ошибки) Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect ('localhost','new','new','new');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo "<h2>Вывод записей:</h2>";

while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "{$user['name']}"; // Вроде ковычки забыли
}
?>
```

Но лучше изучите PDO! Пример использования

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=Имя_хоста;dbname=Имя_БД";
$dbo = new PDO( $dsn, 'Имяпользователя', 'пароль');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$stmt = $dbo->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
while ($user = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ))
    echo "{$user['name']}";
```

Comment: Но еще, конечно, надо проверять успешность соединения и запросов в коде